# S3 putObject not working access denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

AWS S3 is working on my localhost and on my live website, but my development server (which is EXACTLY the same configuration) is throwing the following error: http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/`resulted in a`404 Not Found` response: Error retrieving credentials from the instance profile metadata server.

```
Localhost URL is http://localhost/example
Live URL is http://www.example.com
Development URL is http://dev.example.com
```

Why would this work on localhost and live but not my development server?

Here is my sample code:

```
$bucket = 'example'
$s3Client = new S3Client([
                'region'=>'us-west-2',
                'version'=>'2006-03-01',
                'key'=>'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                'secret'=>'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            ]);
            $uniqueFileName = uniqid().'.txt';
            $s3Client->putObject([
                'Bucket' => $bucket,
                'Key'    => 'dev/'.$uniqueFileName,
                'Body'   => 'this is the body!'
            ]);
```

Here is policy:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "Policyxxxxxxxxx",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Stmtxxxxxxxxx",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::example/*"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: I take it the xxx.xx.xxx.xx that you have redacted is 169.254.169.254?

Comment: That's the standard IP address of the EC2 metadata virtual server, where instance role-based temporary credentials are fetched by your application or AWS libraries.  Why it works on localhost seems like as big of a mystery, if everything is identical.  Are you using instance roles?  Are the two EC2 machines configured with the same roles?

Comment: The `ec2metadata` command line utility accesses that same endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

The values returned by `http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/` are associated with the **Role** assigned to the EC2 instance when the instance was first launched.

Since you are receiving a `404 Not Found` response, it is likely that your Development server **does not have a Role assigned**. You can check in the EC2 management console -- just click on the instance, then look at the details pane and find the Role value.

If you wish to launch a new server that is "fully" identical, use the **Launch More Like This** command in the Actions menu. it will also copy the Role setting.